Why is the /token request hidden in OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow
Using Keycloak for SSO, it implements OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect.
As a client I am using a front-end on Next.js with the Auth.js library for authentication where I can specify Keycloak as the provider.
As far as I understand the default is Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE), since I see code_challenge in the URL.
When I use the Auth.js function to authorize signIn() I am redirected to:
localhost:8089/realms/library-management-api/protocol/openid-connect/auth? response_type=code&client_id=next- frontend&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fkeycloak&code_challenge=rlWdRtDqALBoeb9WUVEIfRz0PsFNbnOjHcxKddDaPF8&code_challenge_method=S256&scope=openid+profile+email

Where after entering the correct username and password and confirming, I see a POST request under the “Network” tab in the browser:
localhost:8089/realms/library-management-api/login-actions/authenticate? session_code=_HaYwLf8ycjvL1XxtSRv76Sap7nneNAMkJzxQsPTbL4&execution=3033ffbc-6446-4d21-8d0e-6b68a7d2d66e&client_id=next- frontend&tab_id=XTy1n3UWkh0&client_data=eyJydSI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MzAwMC9hcGkvYXV0aC9jYWxsYmFjay9rZXljbG9hayIsInJ0IjoiY29kZS

And then a redirect (HTTP 302) to
localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/keycloak?session_state=195c764f-e817-43e3-a0c1-b8542e3da7b1&iss=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8089%2Frealms%2Flibrary-management-api&code=e6393d48-0971-4aa4-823c-31d934ec896c.195 c764f-e817-43e3-a0c1-b8542e3da7b1.96dd514b-55d8-4a86-adcf-fa81608dc794

And then finally I get to the home page of my application localhost:3000/home.
In the URL you can see the code that can be exchanged for access_token and refresh_token.  But in the “Network” tab in the browser I don't see the request for the /realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token endpoint itself, unlike the others I provided above.
How is this hidden? Who is making the request for /token? My client application or Keycloak itself?

Please try to add checks: ["pkce", "state", "nonce"] to your next-auth keycloak provider.

@RoarS. what for?

Use a tool like https://getfiddler.com/ to really see the traffic sent from your client application to get the final fokens. It is your client that do the request to the /token endpoint.

In general I would never to token auth in the browser, why? see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw
